# HTML output in a while loop Syntax Error PHP

Tags: php

I am making a search bar where user can search using post method. Method is not important here but i cant figure out how to echo output blackqoutes in a while loop. if i concatenate all these html then really it looks ugly and also shown error.

```
$searchname = '';
        $last = '';


        if(isset($_POST['q'])) {
            $searchq = $_POST['q'];
            $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
            $searchq = str_replace(' ', '', $searchq);

            $searchquery= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR last LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("Something went wrong! Search Again");

            $countsearch = mysqli_num_rows($searchquery);

            if (empty($_POST['q'])){
                $searchname = 'Sorry no results found!';
            }
            elseif($countsearch == 0) {
                $searchname =  'Sorry No results found';

            } else {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchquery)) {
                     $searchname = $row['q'];
                    $last = $row['q'];



                }
            }

        }

        ?>
        </head>
        <body>

            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0 web lead"><?php echo $searchname ?></p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer lit"><?php echo $last; ?></footer>
              </blockquote>
```

Comment: What is the error shown? Show your error

Comment: The `while` loop will overwrite the variables `$searchname` and `$last` on each iteration if there is more than one result in the recordset - is that the intention?

Comment: @shubranshu Syntax error shown.. RamRaider yes its like more than one results shown.. If the I show results with out while loop than mysqli_fetch_assoc are not getting mulltiple results thats why using while loop here ..

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 43

Comment: keep in mind i cant use foreachloop and also mysqli_fetch_all because i am on shared hosting and they wont allow me to use this ..mysqlind not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but perhaps might help. The results from the sql query ( if there are any ) are added to an array (`$html`) which is printed to screen later on within the document body.

```
<?php
    $html=array();
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['q'] ) ){

        $searchname = 'Sorry no results found!';
        $last = '';

        $searchq = str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace( "#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $_POST['q'] ) );
        $sql="select * from test 
                where name like '%$searchq%' or last like '%$searchq%'";



        $result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $sql );
        $total  = $result ? mysqli_num_rows( $result ) : false;

        if( !$total > 0 ){

            /* simplified html */
            $html[]="
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Sorry No results found</p>
                    <footer></footer>
                </blockquote>";

        } else {
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
                $html[]="
                <blockquote>
                    <p>{$row['q']}</p>
                    <footer>{$row['q']}</footer>
                </blockquote>
                ";
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>mysqli query</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider.. Error Undefined index q in line {row['q']} and also in footer .

Comment: html code :

<form action="search.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="q">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>

Comment: the use of `$row['q']` was taken directly from your original code ~ presumably you have a column in the table `test` called `q`???

Comment: Alright.. I didn't get this.. Thanks so much its working !!